# NASM check if input is a double digit number without a specific Ascii value like "00"

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to detect if the input by the user is `00` but I don't know how to check that. I can check for numbers, or characters that have a specific Ascii value like so:

```
cmp byte [Buff],39h
jbe aMethod
```

`Buff` is where the user input is stored.

How can I check for inputs like `00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check each byte.

```
    cmp byte [Buff],30h
    jne not_00
    cmp byte [Buff+1],30h
    jne not_00
is_00:
    ...
not_00:
    ...
```